# Where can I view SE site usage statistics after launch (like on Area 51)?

Tags: support

[This is a stats page](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1338/gaming) for [gaming.se], but it shows only the data for the beta period. I'd like to see the current statistics, is there a site for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) is for site proposals and monitoring their progress through the private and public beta stages. Once sites graduate they enter the network of full fledged Stack Exchange sites and leave the incubation ground of Area 51. All the launched site can be found on the main [Stack Exchange Network](https://stackexchange.com/) site.

[Current stats](https://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic) for all sites are available. For example [The Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/) shows up in the list of  [recreational sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#recreation-traffic).